# Image margin not pushing the edge of browser page, after javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, margin

So I have a javascript function, which randomly scatters images.

The browser / page window automatically resizes to fit these images (you can't scroll further than the images / the edge of the browser window is the outer edge of the furthest image).

But why is the margin not pushing that boundary further?

So the images have a little extra space before the edge of the window. I don't want the image right up against the edge.

My javascript code:

```
//random position of each Card, 

$(document).ready(function(){

$('img').each(function() {

var top = (Math.random() * 200) 
var left = (Math.random() * 200) 

$(this).css({'top' : top + 'vh'})
$(this).css({'left' : left + 'vw'})

 $(this).css({'margin' : 10 + '%'})

});

});
```

[image: IMG margin not pushing the edge of browser window limits]

Comment: Please provide reproducible example to get clear help

Comment: Have put a photo up above !

Comment: Provide full html example with container, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The image position in your example must be in state of relative/absolute/fixed (because you are using top/left).

In this positions margin don't has effect of pushing the element or the elements around it.

The solution is to use container and change the constant number (200) on the container of the img that will adjust the window proportions.

So, the container will get the img width + Xpx (X is constant number) and position the image inside the container.

Hop I gave a good direction/idea toward the solution in your app.